# Contributing to medical insurance

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, income, withholding

We are hiring a nanny and we would like to contribute to her medical insurance, as our understanding is it would be not be taxable (we are in California). Do we need to purchase the whole insurance or can we just say that part of her income is intended for the insurance?

Answer (score 1):

If you give your nanny a stipend for health insurance, that's taxable income. You may want to consider a QSEHRA account. Your contributions are not taxed and her withdrawals are tax-free too.

[QSEHRAs for Nannies and Other Household Employees](https://gtm.com/household/benefits-insurance/qsehra/)

Comment: Good answers don't just link to another site. That link can rot making the answer worthless. Good answers quote a key point or two from the linked site so that readers can understand why the proposed solution is a good solution.